# dygraph change line color

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I want to change line color off a dygraph chart
with value.
Example when my data is greater than 2, I want to change the color.

I try option color, but is change just the point color.

I make a [JsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/gjdzpesL/).

This is my option dygraph:

```
color: function (color, d) {
    if (typeof d.index === 'undefined') { return color; }

    var val = columns[0][d.index + 1];

    if (val >= 0 && val <= 150) {
        color = 'green';
    } else if (val > 150 && val <= 300) {
        color = 'yellow';
    } else if (val > 300) {
        color = 'red';
    }

    return color;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've discovered, you can't set `color` to a function. You can use the slightly more general [`drawPointCallback` option](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#drawPointCallback), though, which lets you draw any shape with any color for each point:

```
function coloredCircle(g, series, ctx, cx, cy, color, radius, idx) {
  var y = g.getValue(idx, 1);
  var pointColor = y < 5 ? 'green' : 'blue';
  ctx.save();
  ctx.fillStyle = pointColor;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}

g = new Dygraph(
    div, data,
    {
      series: {
        Y: {
          drawPointCallback: coloredCircle,
          pointSize: 5,
          drawPoints: true
        }
      }
    });
```

Here's a [fully-worked fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/10927/). See the [custom-circles demo](http://dygraphs.com/tests/custom-circles.html) for more examples of `drawPointCallback`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your lib is very awesome !