# Change the color of a whole line in Dygraph

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

unfortunately I can't provide code because of security reasons but I will ask my question nonetheless.
I wanted to know if it is possible to change the color of a whole point connection line in dygraphs (js package for plotting data).
I already found this post here on stack: [dygraph-change-line-color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48683519/dygraph-change-line-color/), but this only covers the color changing of circular points on a line and not the line itself.

Even online the topic isn't discussed explicitly and the official documentation doesn't mention this either.

I already searched only and looked through the official documentation but as I mentioned above, I couldn't find anything that covers my question even closely.